# Proof verification (to show that every continuous function is measurable)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

The problem is:

> Show that every *continuous* function $f: \mathbb{R}^d \to [0,+\infty]$ is *measurable*.

I'm trying to use the following *open set* formulation of *measurable function*:

> For all *open set* $U \subset [0,+\infty)$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is *measurable*.

Now if $f$ is *continuous*, then for all *open set* $U \subset [0,+\infty)$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is *open*. We know that all *open sets* are *measurable*. Hence the *open set* formulation is satisfied and we see that $f$ is *measurable*.

The proof seems too straightforward and I'm a bit suspicious about holes in it. Any help, confirmation or correction, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This proof is fine.

The proof seems too straightforward, because what you are trying to prove is elementary, so it does not require sophisticated argument. Since *measurable* functions are much more general then *continuous* functions, it is normal that it is easy to prove that continuous functions are measurable.

Great job!